# How do I ignore the header row with datatables targets?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table where I want to enable clicks on the second column (column 1) as follows:

```
"columnDefs": [
   {
      "className": resetclass, "targets": [1]
   },
]
```

This adds a class to the TDs in that column which I track and then process clicks. But I don't want this applied to the header row because I still want the DataTables sort click to work. What is happening is the added class action click it taking precedence over the sort click. Is there a way to target column 1 EXCEPT for the header (th) row?

Thanks, in advance.

Solution for others: Add addClass command to createdCell

```
{
  'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      $(td).attr('data-id', rowData.id);
      $(td).addClass(resetclass);
   },
   'targets': 1,
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [columns.createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) will work for what you want.

Comment: That was it! I was already using createdCell to add a data-id to those cells so doing an addClass was easy. Didn;t know that createdCell skipped the header row. Thanks!